# Access add new rows

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, error-handling

I have database and when I try to add new row it gives error of Referential Integrity. It says the data can not be added because of referential integrity constraint and foreign key data should be in primary key table. Problem is when I try to add data in Branch table it requires managerNo and in Manager table it requires technicianNo and in Technician table it requires customerNo.

[image]

Comment: You've got at least one too many dependencies in your database, creating a [circular dependency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency). (Note to self: I didn't even know this was possible...) Without knowing your use case, I can't say for sure which it is, but my **guess** is that `Manager` should not have `TechnicianNo`.

Comment: Each branch is managed by one of the technicians working in the branch. The database should record the date the technician started managing the branch and his/her annual bonus.

Comment: Refactoring your database is beyond the scope of the [Q and A Format of our site](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). However, here's another **guess**. Based on your comment, `Branch` doesn't need to know which technician is managing it. I would remove `ManagerNo` from that table and the corresponding FK relationship.

Comment: You've actually got multiple many-to-many relationship in there as one branch can have many managers and one manager can manage many branches, same for technician. One branch can have many technicians, one technician can work at many branches. This is what I see. I'd consider rectifying your table relationships first, before trying to add data. Apply logic before anything else.

Comment: One branch can only have one manager it is defined and one manager can only manage 1 branch

Comment: I know you've defined one branch can have one manager, but look at it from a wider view, its illogical.

Comment: It is defined in my task

Comment: What I'd recommend is, underneath your question, explain your database design.

Comment: One branch can have many technicians but one technician can work at only one branch at a time. They can change branch.

Comment: Every branch has a manager which is working their as technician and every branch can have only 1 manager and 1 manager can only manage 1 branch

Comment: Exactly, one branch can have many technicians, but one technician can only work at one branch.. I do not see that relationship what I see is, one branch can have many technicians, read the relationship backwards, one technician can work at many branches.

Comment: We could into pages and pages of comments defining db logic, but that's not your question, your question is that you can't insert data. Remove the relationships, add the data, redefine the relationships.

Comment: @MuhammadSohailArif can you just define how I can make this relation correct?

Comment: I'll explain in the answer section...

Answer (score 0):

So,

Let's start with the **Branch** table.

```
[Branch] 
brandID, 
buildingnumber
streetname
city
postcode
phone
fax

[Branch_Technicians]
branchID
technicianID

[Technician]
technicianID
name
housenumber
streetname
city
postcode
phonenumber
```

So initially, your relationship was **ONE BRANCH CAN HAVE MANY TECHNICIANS** which is correct, however, what you've got to understand is that **ONE TECHNICIAN CAN WORK AT MANY BRANCHES**, therefore creating a many to many relationship, to resolve this I have created an extra table called **Branch_Technicians** this is called an **Associative Entity.**

I won't complete all of it, I'll let you work out the rest, as I do not have the time to construct an entire database. I could go into greater depth. But this is how I'd do it.. work with this (that's what I'd recommend)

Hope this helps,

Sohail.